# PostgreSQL GRANT SELECT/INSERT on ALL TABLES in a specific database

Tags: postgresql

I would like to GRANT an access for a specific ROLE to SELECT/INSERT ON ALL TABLES within a specific DATABASE.
I wouldn't like this ROLE to have any access to anything else beyond the specific DATABASE.

I am struggling to find anything remotely close to this requirement, which is somewhat confusing given that PostgreSQL documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-overview.html), suggests to use separate `databases` for isolation.

> If one PostgreSQL server cluster is planned to contain unrelated projects or users that should be, for the most part, unaware of each other, it is recommended to put them into separate databases and adjust authorizations and access controls accordingly

When I create new role:

```
CREATE ROLE test LOGIN PASSWORD 'test';
```

by default it can connect to e.g.: `test` and `test2` DBs and list tables:

```
\c test
\t
```

It can't `SELECT` or `INSERT` though in `test`, and it shouldn't be able to connect and list tables in `test2`.

Is there any way to achieve it without specifically including all table names in GRANT command?

Comment: "*it can connect to `test` and `test2` DB*" - that's probably because those databases have `GRANT`ed `CONNECT TO PUBLIC`. Do `REVOKE` that permission if you don't want anyone with cluster auth to introspect the databases.

Comment: You could grant the [pg_read_all_data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html) and pg_write_all_data roles

Comment: `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE reg2 FROM PUBLIC;` combined with `GRANT pg_read_all_data TO reg;` and `GRANT pg_write_all_data TO reg;` somewhat does the job.
What I still don't like is that there is still security context leakage.

`\c reg2` gets: `FATAL:  permission denied for database "reg2"`, but `\c reg3` returns: `FATAL:  database "reg3" does not exist`. 

If an adversary can still iterate and query DB names, then it's not great.